# как создать агрегацию между классами. Список обьектов

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть класс Комната class Room и есть класс Мебель class Furniture. Как путем агрегации связать эти два класса и потом в классе Комната создать метод, что бы выводил весь список мебели?

```
class Room;
class Furniture {
        string chair;
        string cupboard;
        string sofa;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Furniture {
public:
    string chair;
    string sofa;
    string cupboard;

Furniture() {
    chair = "";
    cupboard = "";
    sofa = "";
}

Furniture(string ch, string c, string s) {
    chair = ch;
    cupboard = c;
    sofa = s;
}

void Furniture::print() {
    cout << chair + " " + cupboard + " " + sofa << endl;
    }
};


class Room {
private:
    Furniture f;
public:
    void printFurniture() {
        f.print();
    }
};
```

Полагаю, это то, что вы имели ввиду.

Однако, такая реализация смотрится очень сомнительно. Правда, все зависит от задачи, но создать абстрактный класс `Furniture` и расширить его до `Chair` , `Sofa` , `Cupboard` было бы гораздо удобнее на мой взгляд.

```
class Room {
private: Chair ch;
         Sofa s;
         Cupboard c;
};
```

Comment: СПАСИБО! знаю, не разрешено писать слова благодарности но большое спасибо!!!

Comment: С абстрактным классом тогда уж:
`class Room {
private: std::vector<Furniture*> furniture;
};`

Answer (score 1):

Состояние комнаты не должно  зависить от количества мебели в ней, 
поэтому комната пусть лучше не состоит из мебели, а пусть она состои из окон и дверей, стен и потолков... Поэтому пусть она имеет Furniture* pf, и когда я захочу убрать из комнаты мебель, то это будет легко, т.е. pf = 0. Мебели нет, а комната есть...

```
using std::string;
class Furniture {
    string chair, sofa, cupboard;
    // ...
};
class Room {
    Furniture* pf;
    //...
public:
    Room(Furniture* havings = 0) : pf(havings) {}
    //...
    ~Roome() { delete pf; }        
    Roome& remove furniture() { if(pf) pf = 0; return *this; } // убрать 
    Roome& add_furniture() { ...... }  // добавить
    void show_furniture() const 
    { std::cout << pf->chair  <<'\n' <<pf->sofa <<'\n' << pf->cupboard <<'\n';}
};
```

и когда вы уничтожите комнату, то уничтожится и мебель в ней...

Comment: А почему вы ставите указатель возле Furniture в классе Room?

Comment: я уже обьяснил.  Когда я захочу, чтоб в комнате не было мебели или добавить мебель, я смогу сделать это в методах комнаты. Сейчась добавлю для наглядности

Comment: внимательно прочитайте не только код, но и комментарий - думаю поймете, если нет,  извените - у меня нет практики преодавателья...